# Injection from $\{f: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\} \} \to [0,1]$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For a proof that $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ I have created the following function.
\begin{align*}
\varphi: \{f: \mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}  \} &\to [0,1]\\
f &\mapsto 0,f(1)f(2)f(3)....
\end{align*}
I think it is injective, for suppose $\varphi(f)=\varphi(g)$. Then $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, f(n)=g(n)$, so $f=g$.

My question is, am I missing something? Because I often encounter more involved injections for this proof. Maybe the funtion $\varphi$ is not welldefined because of non-unique decimal representation in [0,1] (but I fail to see how this could be a problem with only 0's and 1's as decimals)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should probably emphasize that the right hand side your mapping ($f\mapsto 0,f(1)f(2)f(3)\ldots$) _is_ a decimal expansion; it would be easy for someone to read it as being intended as a binary expansion, in which case it would not be injective (because of the $0,0111\ldots = 0,1000\ldots$ problem).  One reason why you often find more involved injections is because the authors are trying to craft, not an injection, but a _bi_jection (which your mapping is not, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is fine. Similarly if you restrict to digits in the set $\{0,2\}$ instead of the set $\{0,1\}$ and you interpret the strings of digits in base 3 instead of in base ten, you will get an injection of $\{0,2\}^\mathbb{N}$ into $[0,1]$ and the range of this injection will be the "middle-thirds" Cantor set.

This version of the argument is the one usually used to show that the "middle-thirds" Cantor set is in bijective correspondence with the set of infinite strings over a two-element alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

The map is injective exactly as you said: because reals with a decimal expansion consisting only of $0$ and $1$ have a unique decimal expansion.

Comment: Not quite: reals with a decimal expansion consisting only of $0$'s and $1$'s and which have only finitely many $1$'s have two decimal expansions: one of them ends in $9$'s.  But since the OP is only using $0$'s and $1$'s and not $9$'s for his $\varphi$, his $\varphi$ is still injective.

Comment: @StefanSmith Good point!

Comment: Thanks for not taking offense (some folks here are pretty thin-skinned).  When I do something like this, for example Cantor's Diagonal Proof, I avoid $0$ and $9$ altogether to avoid this issue.  I usually use $5$ and $7$.

Comment: actually my criticism may not be 100% accurate because $0 = 0.000\ldots$ has exactly one decimal expansion, contains no digits other than $0$ and $1$, and has finitely many $1$'s (none).  I should have added that such a problematic number has at least one $1$ in its decimal expansion.